# Switch with If Else to change Backgrounds

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm working on a Weather Project.

I want to change backgrounds for certain conditions. I accomplished this using `switch` statements. Then I decided that it looked dumb to have day-time pics when it was night. I thought I could use an `if else` with the `switch` statements I already had and switch statements for night-time pics but that isn't working.

Having a trouble with my background images resizing for mobile

```
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Tamtamwilson/full/wPZJMK/)
```

Comment: Can you post your code that is causing the error?

Comment: Code relevant to your problem belongs directly into your question, not just on external sites. Please edit accordingly.

Comment: Instead of going with a massive switch statement, it might make more sense to put the data into an array/object strucutre, so that you can simply _look up_ the appropriate image for a key such as `thunderstorm` in there. That way, you could also easily provide _two_ images, one for night and one for day, and pick the appropriate one automatically.